# Behaviour of as.Date when format = ""

Tags: r, date-format, typecast-operator

I have a simple question.

How does the function `as.Date` work?

Can anyone explain why a simple `""` changes everything in the code below?

```
as.Date("03/04/2019")
#[1] "0003-04-19"

as.Date("03/04/2019", "")
#[1] "2019-07-16"
```

Comment: `""` specifies the format, in the former it takes the default one. Note that none of your line is correct. `as.Date("03/04/2019", "%d/%m/%Y")` or `as.Date("03/04/2019", "%m/%d/%Y")` will work though. (why the `+3`?)

Comment: Default date format is `yyyy-mm-dd` and your value is `03-04-19` so you get `0003-04-23` as a result of adding 3 days (after conversion). In your second code, you get 3 days added to the current date, I assume because you did not pass a valid format. Bottom line: You are assuming the wrong date format as the default and not passing the correct values to these arguments.

Comment: In the second case see the second sentence of the second paragraph of section `Note` of help page `as.Date`. The format string is wrong so R assumes you are passing the current day. And today is `"2019-07-16"`.

Comment: You can see the code by typing `as.Date.character`, and get details on how it works with `?as.Date`

Answer (score 2):

This is directly from the help page which you view with `?as.Date`:

```
## S3 method for class 'character'
as.Date(x, format, tryFormats = c("%Y-%m-%d", "%Y/%m/%d"),
        optional = FALSE, ...)
```

- x: an object to be converted.
- format:  character string. If not specified, it will try tryFormats one by one on the first non-NA element, and give an error if none works. Otherwise, the processing is via strptime.

So, in the first case we do not provide `format`. In this case `as.Date` tries the following formats:  "year-month-day" and "year/month/day". The second one "works" in this case so we get the following return:

```
as.Date("03/04/2019") 
[1] "0003-04-20"
```

"03" is interpreted as year, "04" as month and "2019" as day. Since day can only have to digits only the first two digits are used.

In the second case we provide format ourselves:

```
as.Date("03/04/2019", format = "") 
[1] "2019-07-16"
```

If `format` is provided `as.Date` does not try any formats. Instead `strptime("03/04/2019", format = "")` is returned.
In the help page of `strptime` you can find the following:

> For strptime the input string need not specify the date completely: it
>   is assumed that unspecified seconds, minutes or hours are zero, and an
>   unspecified year, month or day is the current one.

So you provide a format but it does not contain anything so the current date is returned.

In any case, you can simply specify the format yourself:

```
as.Date("03/04/2019", format = "%d/%m/%Y") 
[1] "2019-04-03"
```

Comment: The surprising thing is what `strptime` does there. I cannot find in the documentation that the current date is returned for any character string input if `format = ""`.

Comment: @Roland from the help page of `strptime`: For strptime the input string need not specify the date completely: it is assumed that unspecified seconds, minutes or hours are zero, and an unspecified year, month or day is the current one.

Comment: Yes, but what OP observes is about the format string and not about the input string.

Comment: E.g., check out `as.Date("1969-07-21", "") `.

Comment: @ Roland `as.Date("1969-07-21", "")` returns the current date as well: "2019-07-17"

Comment: That's my point. I didn't expect this from the documentation.

Comment: Oh, now I get it: the input string is `x` not `format`.